# Why does the KDE lock screen appear in Regolith Desktop when installed alongside Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, lock-screen, settings, i3-wm

I recently installed Regolith Desktop to use alongside Kubuntu Desktop. I have fully disabled screen locking in Kubuntu, such that my display just goes to sleep without needing a password to resume.

However, when I am using Regolith and my screen goes to sleep and I wake it up, I get a KDE-branded lock screen dialog and have to enter my password. Because the screen unlocker has a KDE logo, I assume this is somehow coming from the Kubuntu side.

How might that be happening and what must I change in order to have lock-free monitor sleep in Regolith?